# Iceberg GCS and Consistency

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-iceberg

Does iceberg support writing data into GCS? Because for the iceberg's atomicity to work according to https://iceberg.apache.org/java-api-quickstart/, GCS should support atomic rename, however from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv GCS renames are not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop table implementation is the only place where rename is used, and
it requires a file system that supports atomic rename. If you're using an
object store like S3 or GCS, then you should be using the HMS
implementation or a custom catalog instead of Hadoop tables.

> Tables do not require rename, except for tables that use atomic rename to
> implement the commit operation for new metadata files.

Everything should work with GCS without modification as far as I know.

There is no native atomic rename in GCS, it requires a move + delete. You can refer to the page https://iceberg.apache.org/spec/#mvcc-and-optimistic-concurrency.

source: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/iceberg-dev/201909.mbox/%3cCAO4re1kFEbVyfZJFiq=CfUDhB7opfT-ntwF7+7_oFt=Kwjk0XQ@mail.gmail.com%3e